# (FitNesse, Xebium, Selenium IDE) How to use Xebium format to click on a label?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, fitnesse, fitness

I'm a very new for `Xebium`.
I cannot use

```
| ensure | do | click | on | id=text |
```

to click on a checkbox because it is a label, id is look like hidden. 
So, is there any way to click from label?

thank you for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to find your desired element. If you have the following structure of your `form`:

```xml
<form action="target.html">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sex" id="male" value="male"><br />
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sex" id="female" value="female"><br />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

, then you could the following `Xebium` command to click on the label with `Female` as value:

```
 | ensure | do | click | on | xpath=(//label[contains(text(),'Female')]) |
```

You can also use the following command, if you want to click in the check box that is coupled to a specific label:

```
| ensure | do | click | on | xpath=(//input[contains(preceding-sibling::label/text(),'Male')])|
```

If your label tag is after your input tag, you have to change `preceding-sibling` to `following-sibling`.

Note; you can try this out on [w3schools xpath examples](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_label). That example uses radio buttons instead of check boxes. Since the example occurs in an `iFrame`, you have to move into the frame by `selectFrame|iframeResult`.